# Self-join not working as expected with the DataFrame API

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to get the latest records from a table using self join. It works using `spark-sql` but not working using spark `DataFrame` API.

Can anyone help? Is it a bug?

I am using Spark 2.2.0 in local mode

Creating input `DataFrame`:

```
scala> val df3 = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Array((1,"a",1),(1,"aa",2),(2,"b",2),(2,"bb",5))).toDF("id","value","time")
df3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, value: string ... 1 more field]    

scala> val df33 = df3
df33: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, value: string ... 1 more field]

scala> df3.show
+---+-----+----+
| id|value|time|
+---+-----+----+
|  1|    a|   1|
|  1|   aa|   2|
|  2|    b|   2|
|  2|   bb|   5|
+---+-----+----+

scala> df33.show
+---+-----+----+
| id|value|time|
+---+-----+----+
|  1|    a|   1|
|  1|   aa|   2|
|  2|    b|   2|
|  2|   bb|   5|
+---+-----+----+
```

Now performing the join using SQL: **works**

```
scala> spark.sql("select df33.* from df3 join df33 on df3.id = df33.id and df3.time < df33.time").show
+---+-----+----+
| id|value|time|
+---+-----+----+
|  1|   aa|   2|
|  2|   bb|   5|
+---+-----+----+
```

Now performing the join using dataframe API: **doesn't work**

```
scala> df3.join(df33, (df3.col("id") === df33.col("id")) && (df3.col("time") < df33.col("time")) ).select(df33.col("id"),df33.col("value"),df33.col("time")).show
+---+-----+----+
| id|value|time|
+---+-----+----+
+---+-----+----+
```

The thing to notice is the explain plans: **blank for the `DataFrame` API!!**

```
scala> df3.join(df33, (df3.col("id") === df33.col("id")) && (df3.col("time") < df33.col("time")) ).select(df33.col("id"),df33.col("value"),df33.col("time")).explain
== Physical Plan ==
LocalTableScan <empty>, [id#150, value#151, time#152]

scala> spark.sql("select df33.* from df3 join df33 on df3.id = df33.id and df3.time < df33.time").explain
== Physical Plan ==
*Project [id#1241, value#1242, time#1243]
+- *SortMergeJoin [id#150], [id#1241], Inner, (time#152 < time#1243)
   :- *Sort [id#150 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   :  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#150, 200)
   :     +- *Project [_1#146 AS id#150, _3#148 AS time#152]
   :        +- *SerializeFromObject [assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple3, true])._1 AS _1#146, staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString,
assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple3, true])._2, true) AS _2#147, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple3, true])._3 AS _3#148]
   :           +- Scan ExternalRDDScan[obj#145]
   +- *Sort [id#1241 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(id#1241, 200)
         +- *Project [_1#146 AS id#1241, _2#147 AS value#1242, _3#148 AS time#1243]
            +- *SerializeFromObject [assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple3, true])._1 AS _1#146, staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString,
assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple3, true])._2, true) AS _2#147, assertnotnull(input[0, scala.Tuple3, true])._3 AS _3#148]
               +- Scan ExternalRDDScan[obj#145]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No that's not a bug, but when you reassign the DataFrame to a new one like what you have done, it actually copies the lineage but it doesn't duplicate the data. Thus you'll be comparing on the same column.

Use `spark.sql` is slightly different because it's actually working on aliases of your `DataFrame`s

So the *correct way to perform a self-join using the API* is actually *aliasing* your `DataFrame` as followed :

```
val df1 = Seq((1,"a",1),(1,"aa",2),(2,"b",2),(2,"bb",5)).toDF("id","value","time")

df1.as("df1").join(df1.as("df2"), $"df1.id" === $"df2.id" && $"df1.time" < $"df2.time").select($"df2.*").show
// +---+-----+----+
// | id|value|time|
// +---+-----+----+
// |  1|   aa|   2|
// |  2|   bb|   5|
// +---+-----+----+
```

For more information about self-joins, I recommend reading  [High Performance Spark by Rachel Warren, Holden Karau - Chapter 4](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/high-performance-spark/9781491943199/ch04.html).